# Use function from another php file onclick of the button

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm  trying to show a PDF on a click of a button.

I have a function **getPDFfile($id)** on my viewCrf.php

And I have my listCrf.php file which include viewCrf.php.
listCrf.php is a table that shows all the list of the data from the DB.

On the table. there is a column for **View PDF**.
It is a button when `onclick`, it should pass the `$id` and go to viewCrf.php that shows the generated PDF file and the data where ID = $id.

How do I call the `getPDFfile($id)` function from  viewCrf.php file when
I click the button on the View PDF column?

**listCrf.php**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
            $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * from crf");
            $sql->execute();    
                while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    echo " 
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$result['col_ID']."</td>
                        <td>".$result['col_fn'].$result['col_ln']."</td>
                        <td><input type='button' value='View PDF'class='btn btn-primary' onclick='viewPDF(this.id)'></td>
                    </tr>
                    ";
                }

        ?>

        <tbody>        
</table>
```

**viewCrf.php**

```
$id = $_POST['iddd'];
$q  =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM crf where col_ID = ".$id);
    while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        $last               = $r['col_ln'];
        $first              = $r['col_fn'];
        $middle             = $r['col_mi'];
        $civilstatus        = $r['col_civilstat'];
        $sex                = $r['col_gender'];
        $dob                = $r['col_bday'];             
    }
```

**UPDATE**

So I tried ajax.

```
   function viewPDF(id){
        var theID = id;
        var dataString = "iddd=" + theID;
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "viewCrf.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: [`AJAX`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) is your friend.

Comment: Also you could use `<a href="path/and/param" target="_blank">View</a>` this would open a new tab

Comment: @Script47 I tried AJAX, but I get this error `Undefined index: iddd in C:\xampp\htdocs\renewSAD\agent\viewCrf.php on line 3`. Please refer to my edited post above.